# Xcode version 11 on MacOS Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter

Is there anyway to install Xcode version 11 or any new versions of Xcode on a MacOS Sierra? I don't want to buy a new one and I also don't want to upgrade to a new version using a patch tool. I am trying to use Flutter but can't because it requires Xcode version 11. Is there anyway to maybe change the configuration and let it run on it?

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode 11 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes) mentions that;

> Xcode 11 requires a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later

So you'll need to find a way to upgrade your OS.

Comment: It requires High Sierra and refuses to run on Sierra, but you can make it run. Do that at your own risk, of course. It requires using xcodebuild from 9.2, which may or may not break something. In my testing, it works fine Edit Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist and change the Minimum System Version to 10.12.6 Do the same for Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/Info.plist (might require a restart of Xcode and/or Mac OS to make it open the simulator on run) Replace Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild with one from 9.2 Is this possible to do?

Comment: The link to the post is this. https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/89p5hw/cant_install_xcode_93_on_macos_sierra_10126/

Comment: If you are willing to tweak parts of your software you could also tweak parts of your OS and upgrade it in my opinion. I haven't tried but you can give it a go.

Comment: Is it possible to tweak the system requirements in Xcode? I want to see if I can use Xcode 11 because flutter requires it

Comment: If it is just a short term thing you can try one of the Rent-a-mac on the cloud services. They can be convenient if you are not willing to invest in a new Mac